# Non linear Burgers equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We consider the non linear Burgers equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{u^2(x,t)}{2}\Big)=0$$

We approximate this equation by the following scheme
\begin{align}\frac{v_{j}^{n+1}-v_j^n}{\Delta t}+\frac{(v_{j+1}^{n})^2-(v_{j}^{n})^2}{2\Delta x}=0\quad\quad\quad (1)\end{align}
where $v_j^n\simeq u(x_j,t^n)$ with $x_j=j\Delta x$ and $t^n=n\Delta t$

Could you please help me to write the relation (1) in the following form
$$v_j^{n+1}=H\Big(v_{j-1}^n,v_{j}^n,v_{j+1}^n\Big)$$

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your expression in $(1)$ has a typo, the spatial discretisation should be $(v_{j+1}^{n})^{2} - (v_\color{red}{{j-1}}^{n})^{2}$. Then rearranging, you get $$v_{j}^{n+1} = v_{j}^{n} - \frac{\Delta t}{2 \Delta x} \left( (v_{j+1}^{n})^{2} - (v_{j-1}^{n})^{2} \right) = H(v_{j-1}^{n}, v_{j}^{n}, v_{j+1}^{n})$$

Comment: The proposed scheme reads
$$v_{j}^{n+1}=v_j^n - \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}\left(\tfrac12(v_{j+1}^{n})^2-\tfrac12(v_{j}^{n})^2\right) $$ which is of the desired form. @mattos Note the coefficient $1/2$ in the PDE $u_t + (\frac12 u^2)_x = 0$.

Comment: @EditPiAf I assumed because $H$ in the post is functionally dependent on $v_{j-1}^{n}$, that the OP was using a central difference scheme. not a forward difference and so had made a typo. In which case I also made a typo.